# Checking for next available date using MySQLi database

Tags: php, mysqli, calendar

I am building a website for a guy who owns and lets out a caravan, he wanted a way for the clients to check for available dates. I have been using this basic script which searches for any results between the two dates entered in to the form, and returns if any results have been found.

Here is the current code:

```
<?
             if(isset($_POST['available'])){
                 $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
                 $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `foiu51r_calendar` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND  '" . $end_date . "'";
    $results = $conn->query($sql);

if ($results->num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Available -</b> The caravan is available for the dates between <b>'.$start_date.'</b> and <b>'.$end_date.'</b>! - <a href="contact.php">Book this holiday!</a></div>';
} else {
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>Sorry!</b> These dates are not available, please try again or <a href="contact.php">contact us</a>... </div>';
}
             }
             ?>
```

A couple things wrong here which I cannot seem to figure out are:

1. The caravan can be moved in to on the same day somebody is leaving, so say the caravan was booked from 1/1/16 - 8/1/16, if I entered the dates 8/1/16 - 10/1/16 it should show as available. But I have no idea how to do this.
2. It would be handy, but not entirely necessary, to show the next available moving in date. If I entered 6/1/16 - 10/1/16, it should show something like: `These dates are not available - next available date is 8/1/16`.

If anybody has any idea on how to configure the script to show these results that would be helpful? Thanks.

Comment: Sidenote: Since this is for a live site, you're leaving it open to a serious SQL injection. You don't want your client's site to go down, *right?*

Comment: Can it still be SQL injected if the input type=date I assumed it was only text ?

Comment: Indeed it can; use a prepared statement. Plus, your `if ($results->num_rows == 0)` will fail, since you're wanting to show it as being available. That should read as `if ($results->num_rows > 0)` - `num_rows == 0` is interpreted as "if no results".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['available'])){
     $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
     $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `foiu51r_calendar` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND  '" . $end_date . "'";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
$counter = mysqli_num_rows($results);

  if ($counter >= 1) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Available -</b> The caravan is available for the dates between <b>'.$start_date.'</b> and <b>'.$end_date.'</b>! - <a href="contact.php">Book this holiday!</a></div>';
  } else {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><b>Sorry!</b> These dates are not available, please try again or <a href="contact.php">contact us</a>... </div>';
  }
}
?>
```

For 2nd version you need a flag called available in your db and make it 1 in the date the caravan is available:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['available'])){
     $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
     $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `foiu51r_calendar` WHERE `date` BETWEEN '" . $start_date . "' AND  '" . $end_date . "'";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
$counter = mysqli_num_rows($results);

  if ($counter >= 1) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><b>Available -</b> The caravan is available for the dates between <b>'.$start_date.'</b> and <b>'.$end_date.'</b>! - <a href="contact.php">Book this holiday!</a></div>';
  } else {
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM `foiu51r_calendar` WHERE `available` = 1";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      $available_date = $result['date'];
      echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><b>Sorry!</b> These dates are not available. Next available date: '$available_date'";
  }
}
?>
```